# Do Paypal held transactions generate IPN callbacks?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm having trouble getting to the bottom of a bug that seems to stem from our system not having received an IPN callback for a held transaction. 
Here is the transaction history as shown on the Paypal website:

[image: Transaction history from Paypal]

And here are the callbacks that registered on our system:

[image: Callbacks received]

On Jul 25 we received only one callback, for the payment, but none for the temporary hold that's showing on the Paypal site. This is leading to incorrect balances, as it should balance out to zero in this example, but in our database it ends up giving the customer $200 credit.

From the site and docs I don't find any mention of callbacks for held transactions, and it's not on the list of callbacks I can test as far as I can see:

- Canceled_Reversal
- Completed
- Denied
- Expired
- Failed
- In-Progress
- Partially_Refunded
- Pending
- Processed
- Refunded
- Reversed
- Voided

I'm unsure whether our system just missed a callback, or whether there is none to be expected and we should be doing something else. What is the expected sequence of events in the case where a transaction is put on "Temporary Hold"? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have missed a Reversed callback which took the funds out.

If the case was decided in your favour you will then get a Canceled_Reversal transaction which gives you the funds back again.

Comment: I see, so I should have gotten a Reversed callback. Okay, thanks!